# How can give click functionality of html elements in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am facing little bit problem regarding asp, I am making grid by
assigning template of li's and in these li's I have button tag.

When clicking this button I want some functionality so how can attach event and give logic .aspx.cs file.

Here is what I am doing:-

```
Label1.Text += "<li style='text-align:center;'><img src='../../Images/thumbs/" 
 + finfo.Name + "'  /></br><button filePath='../../Images/thumbs/" + finfo.Name 
 + "'>Delete</botton></li>";
```

You can see button tag so I want to attach click event and want to implementaion in aspx.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `HtmlGenericControl` and `Button` server side control.

```
HtmlContainerControl Container = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
//set it's style etc 

//use button class and add it in Container 
Button b=new Button();
b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
//set it's property an on click event

//add it to li;
Container.Controls.Add(b);

Label1.Controls.Add(container);

protected void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your process you want to do on click.
}
```

Or better is to create a Method `Page-Method` or `service` or `http-generic-handler` and call it using java-script or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give name for the button on the fly (eg:"button+YourPrimaryKeyOfData"), and in page_load you can see PostBack properties to see the postBack source and implement the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for trigering click event for each an every html controls in your Application.

```
$("#IdOfYourElement").click(function()
 {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
 });
```